# How do I add a hyperlink to text inside a tooltip?

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink, href

I have a tooltip as part of my input field which is an external component you can use like shown in the code below. In the tooltip, I want to add a hyperlink so that when you open the tooltip and see 'hello world', you can click on the word 'world' and get taken to another page. When I attempted to add an a href I got an error saying `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'div'.`

```
          <Input.Field
            name="name"
            label="some text"
            tooltip="hello "<a href="www.helloworld.com">world</a>""
          />
```

Comment: Try `tooltip="hello <a href='www.helloworld.com'>world</a>"`. Note single quotes around the link.

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<Input.Field
            name="name"
            label="some text"
            tooltip={
          <p>
            Hello
            <a href="www.helloworld.com">World</a>
          </p>
          />
```